# Unable to create a prepared MySql DB using docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to create a prepared Mysql DB using Docker compose, the outcome is to create the "*INTERVIEW*" Database and give the username "*ADMIN*" the access to it.

For this purpose, the folder setup_scripts contains the sql script(*create_user.sql*) as below to grant access:

```
grant all privileges on INTERVIEW.* to 'ADMIN'@'%' with grant option;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The docker compose file:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.17
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - '32768:3306'
    volumes:
      - "./my-db-data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./setup_scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"

volumes:
  my-db:
```

And the .env file:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE='INTERVIEW'
MYSQL_USER='ADMIN'
MYSQL_PASSWORD='password'
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'
```

Upon docker-compose up, the below error is seen, but i am unable to debug the source of the issue:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''' at line 1

Is there a way to see verbose logs for the db startup to understand the file where the error originates?.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the env-file declaration:

it should be as below:

```
env_file:
      - ./.env
```